# Get column names of a data frame based on values from a list in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df as follows (only 1 row):

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
a1       b1     c_d      d1      e10
```

I have another list val = [a1, c_d, e10]. I want to get the column names for the values present in val. In this case the column names will be in a list, colnm = [col1,col3,col5].
I did the same in R using:

```
names(df)[which((df %in% val) == TRUE)]
```

But not able to figure out in python as I am new in Python. Any help will be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: There is always one row `DataFrame` ? Or multiple rows?

Comment: in my case there is always one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General soluion for multiple rows - tested if at least one value or if all values per columns has values from `val`.

You can test membership by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and then test by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
#added new row for see difference
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0   a1   b1  c_d   d1  e10
1   a1   d1  c_e   f1  e10

val = ['a1', 'c_d', 'e10']

#tested membership
print (df.isin(val))
   col1   col2   col3   col4  col5
0  True  False   True  False  True
1  True  False  False  False  True

#test if at least one True per column
print (df.isin(val).any())
col1     True
col2    False
col3     True
col4    False
col5     True
dtype: bool

#test if all Trues per column
print (df.isin(val).all())
col1     True
col2    False
col3    False
col4    False
col5     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
names = df.columns[df.isin(val).any()]
print (names)
Index(['col1', 'col3', 'col5'], dtype='object')

names = df.columns[df.isin(val).all()]
print (names)
Index(['col1', 'col5'], dtype='object')
```

If DataFrame has only one row is possible seelct first row for `Series` by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
names = df.columns[df.iloc[0].isin(val)]
```

EDIT: If not help upgdare to last version of pandas here is one solution for repalce all object columns with no strings to missing values:

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'content': [{'values': 3}]},
    {'id': 2, 'content': 'a1'},
    {'id': 3, 'content': 'c_d'},
    {'id': 4, 'content': np.array([4,5])}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask1 = ~df.columns.isin(df.select_dtypes(object).columns)
mask2 = df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))

df = df.where(mask2 | mask1)
print (df)
   id content
0   1     NaN
1   2      a1
2   3     c_d
3   4     NaN

val = ['a1', 'c_d', 'e10']
print (df.isin(val))
      id  content
0  False    False
1  False     True
2  False     True
3  False    False
```

Comment: Hi The above code works fine for some cases, for some other cases I am getting following error. I don't know why:
SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x125e48f30> returned a result with an error set

Comment: Sorry but I can not share the real data as it is confidential. I will check what's wrong. But is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @user3642360 - hmmm, it seems problem is [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20883)

Comment: @user3642360 - So problem is there are some arrays in data, pandas `isin` failed.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I will look into it.

Comment: @user3642360 - If still problem one solution added to answer.